# Getting the alias from a sql file using python

Tags: python, sql, jinja2, dbt

I have a project in dbt. Some of the sql files have aliases using jinja (see below). I would like to use python to get the alias of a particular file (i.e. if no alias, use the filename, if there is an alias use that). In theory I could look for strings within the file to try to locate "alias" but I feel like that would be error prone considering the word alias sometimes appears in other contexts in some files and the exact way it's written is different between files. Is there some simple way to specifically look at the jinja and get the alias value?

Example file:

```
{{
    config(alias='my_alias')
}}

(some sql query...)
```

Answer (score 1):

From within a dbt project (probably a macro or jinja directly in a model file), you can access the `graph` context variable, which is a dictionary containing all of the config and properties for all of the resources defined in dbt. To access the `graph` node for the currently-executing model, you can use `model`. So to access a model's alias from the model sql itself, this will work:

```sql
{{
    config(alias='my_alias')
}}

select
    '{{ model.config.alias if execute else "" }}' as config_alias,
    '{{ model.alias if execute else "" }}' as resolved_alias
```

If you want to write a Python script that executes separately from dbt, you can read dbt's `manifest.json` artifact. See the [docs for the Manifest](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/artifacts/manifest-json). Most dbt commands produce (or update) the manifest, which by default is written to the `target` directory within your dbt project directory.

Models are under a key called `nodes`, and are keyed by their fully qualified resource name: `model.my_project.my_model`

```py
import json

with open("target/manifest.json") as f:
    manifest = json.load(f)

config_alias = manifest["nodes"]["model.jaffle_shop.orders"]["config"]["alias"]
print(config_alias)

resolved_alias = manifest["nodes"]["model.jaffle_shop.orders"]["alias"]
print(resolved_alias)
```

Note that `config_alias` will be `None` unless an alias is explicitly configured for that model; `resolved_alias` will never be `None`, since it will be resolved to the model's name if no alias is configured.